# Azure AD SSO authorisation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am new to SSO and am hoping someone could help me clarify the following.

I am doing an Azure AD SSO integration with a third party application. The application has 6 roles specified, each with specific permission. The users have to be created in the application.

1. Am I right to assume that the application does not provide auto provisioning as I am required to create  users in the application?
2. Do I have to add the same users in Azure AD too? How does Azure AD knows what role to grant the users since the roles are specified in the applications?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Question 1

There are 3 main types of provisioning:

- **Manual provisioning**
- **Just-In-Time (JIT) provisioning** (users are automatically created at the time of login)
- **Automatic provisioning** (users are automatically synchronized on a periodic basis)

If you have to create the users in the application, then it would be manual provisioning. Some applications don't support JIT or automatic provisioning, you'll have to check with the application vendor to see what's supported.

#### Question 2

No, you wouldn't have to add those users in Azure AD, unless they don't already exist for some reason. Between Azure AD and the client app, the 2 user identities from each platform will be linked together with a common attribute passed along during login, which is typically the **UserPrincipalName**.

**Authorization**

How the roles will be determined will again depend on the application's capabilities. If you're assigning the roles from the application, then probably there will be no configuration from Azure AD. Understand that the roles are created in the application, and used by the application, Azure AD doesn't have any knowledge of the roles. Azure AD can only pass along a helper hint to the application of what roles the user should have, and the application would have a pre-determined "mapping" of this Azure AD hint to an application role.

Some applications will assign roles based on attributes that are passed during SSO, such as the user's AD group membership (e.g. if user is in this group, assign user this role), or a `role` attribute in the token.